# Why the blender browser plugin is not updated?

Tags: game-engine, add-on

You can create blender games and make it run on browsers using Blender Browser Plugin. Just wanted to know why the browser plugin is not maintained? If it is available, it will make a huge platform for developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plug-in you were using before was a third party addon l, which seems to have been discontinued. There seems to be a new one called [Burster](http://geta3d.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=20).
It was developed specifically for Blender and integrates rather well with both Blender and the Web browser in which it runs.

Comment: Yup blender Buster 3d looks encouraging. And now we can forget unity 3D.

Comment: Will you add more to this answer? As it is now it could be a link only  comment.

Comment: @David Good enough yet? There's not much else I can add so you can delete it if you think it's appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative.  You can also have a look at blend4web which can directly export to an HTML file and since it uses WebGL, no browser plugin is needed.   It can also export to a more programmer oriented format for use with some of their other tools.

So far as I know, it is not yet capable of using BGE logic bricks however b4w is being updated regularly and can already be used to make really nice looking browser games.  There is also a lot of documentation available so getting started should not be too difficult.

https://www.blend4web.com/en/

Here is a BA.org thread that is currently being maintained by an employee of blend4web  http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?333214-Blend4Web-a-3D-web-framework-for-Blender-artists