# Exporting interactive Flash content

Tags: export, image

Does anyone know if it its possible to export an interactive interface with an image with Blender for Flash? I'm sure its possible but think I may be missing a few plugins. Thanks!

Comment: " I'm sure its possible " you say, but based on what evidence? You can render raster animations , if that's what you mean.. but authoring .fla or .swf interactive files is not something that i've seen Blender plugins for. Flash is almost on its last legs, what do you need it for? Web-based interactive interfaces?

Comment: Thanks for your response and I appreciate your help! I am indeed hoping to create a web-based interactive feature/ interface which responds to simple user commands pan, grip, zoom etc. I have been experimenting with Blender for this application over the last three months but have been unable to figure out if it can export such a feature for online purposes. Flash has hosted such content in the past but I would prefer to stay away from this avenue if possible. Any advice?

Comment: I don't believe it to be possible. You can render out flash video, but not interactive stuff. However, if your aim is to have the flash content in a webpage, you could look into Blend4web. Instead of a webpage with Flash, you get a BGE game as HTML5. This also theoretically works on mobile devices (though often low fps)

Comment: Try exporting using three.js

Comment: the Blend4Web is the way to go, even NASA used it:  https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/139/

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I have had a look at Blend4Web and it sounds like it is perfectly capable of programming out the interactive, visual interface that I have been striving to develop! Thanks for your advice everyone, I appreciate all of your help and expertise!

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to export a raster animation for Flash, (`.flv`). There are no Blender plugins (or native features) that let you author `.fla` or `.swf` interactive content. Some parts of the flash format remain closed source, but if someone really wanted [they could using the MXMLC compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF).

The grasp that Flash once had on the interactive web has faded significantly with the growing improvements in JavaScript and adjacent technologies. Egged on a little by [Apple's decision to stop supporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_and_Adobe_Flash_controversy) Flash directly on it's mobile devices. In light of recent (July 2015) revelations about years-old, but profound, security issues, the public's sense of trust in Flash isn't improving.

There are solutions for getting Blender content online and animated + interactive:

- Code WebGL directly
- Three.js
- Blend4Web

  - intended to make the process a lot easier, a shining endorsement is the fact that [NASA uses](https://www.blend4web.com/en/article/139/) it. See this other answer about interactive web tech built with a direct pipeline from Blender.
    [Why the blender browser plugin is not updated?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/why-the-blender-browser-plugin-is-not-updated/18604#18604)