# How to make web games with Blender?

Tags: game-engine, export, blend4web, eevee-render-engine

I'd like to make games within Blender, and then have them run inside a web browser, ie. have the Javascript code somehow be "made" or "exported".
I'm *especially* curious to know whether this will be possible with the new "Eevee" thing in 2.8? can I simply *play* the game inside Blender, and, subsequently, on the web? I have zero experience with Blender so far, but I'd love to learn, IF it is possible.

If it is not possible within Blender alone, can I use Unreal Engine in conjunction with it to achieve the above? And - is it humanly possible to learn BOTH together?

Comment: Link : https://www.blend4web.com/en/
Solved? Blender for Web

Answer (score 4):

While still in development [Armory](http://armory3d.org/) looks to be a promising solution. It has multiple export options including HTML5.

It is open source and maintains a GitHub repository [here](https://github.com/armory3d).

Here [is an example](http://armory3d.org/demo/scene5/) of an HTML5 game.

**EDIT**

The best way to get Armory is through Armory's [Patreon](https://www.patreon.com/bePatron?u=3705855) page.
Building from GitHub is a difficult if not impossible task at the moment.

Comment: Thanks - just took a cursory look, but I'll start digging around seriously later! :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure. Regarding EEVEE and BGE, have a look at [UPBGE](https://upbge.org/). They have [already implemented EEVEE support](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NIhkdTTFAZs) but not sure about HTML5 exports.

Comment: Can you link me to any tutorials on how to compile the armory source code into an executable ? I am still scratching my head for the past few months.

Comment: @Retrax Hmmm. I tried using the add-on for Blender but not much worked. I think you need the full bundle which includes a modified version of Blender. At the moment I think that is only available through the crowd funding scheme: [https://www.patreon.com/armory](https://www.patreon.com/armory)

Comment: Armory is Open Source and is based on open source technologies. The developer made it clear from the beginning that custom blender builds and addon are required which you can get through his patreon  or itch.io. Also, his patreon goal never changed.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Misunderstanding on my part.

Answer (score 0):

It is currently **not possible** to export your blender game to HTML5.

***However***, there <s>is</s> **was** a web plugin that would enable you to run your blender game through the browser. THe plugin is called Burster, and is not maintained. More info can be [found here.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/18571/why-the-blender-browser-plugin-is-not-updated)

Comment: The link "geta3d.com" leads nowhere......